# how to get multiple images to appear facebook sharer (more than 3)

Tags: facebook-sharer

I have implemented a facebook sharer url using https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[URL]

I have used the fb debugger tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object) in order to see what fb sees when viewing my page, and it gets everything correctly.

Basically I want to be able to have more than 3 images so the user can select which one they want to share.

Currently the problem is that only the first 3 images appear in the sharer dialog, but in the lint tool all the images appear correctly, there are over 10, some pages will have around 30, and I still wish all of them to appear in the order they are in og:image meta tag.

Does anyone have idea how to get more than 3 images to appear?

Comment: I think Facebook limited the number of images they show to a maximum of three a while ago.

Comment: that's what I was worried about, i found a lot of screenshots on the internet with like 20+ images, but found nothing on the 3 limit, other than it doesn't show more then 3 ever. It would have been nice to be able to confirm this somewhere in the facebook docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit of 3 images, for those that are wondering, but I do not have the link. I forgot to bring it back here, just remembered today that someone might be reading this.